have a code for copying rows from a sheet to another in google sheet but it do all of the rows not working for selected or filtered
I have a code for copying rows from a sheet (Parks) to another (Report) in google sheet. It works fine but the problem is, I have 335 rows in sheet 'Parks' and I don't want all of these rows in my Sheet 'Report'.
I want to apply filter on sheet 'Parks' so it might remain like 14 rows in sheet 'Parks'. I want the code to copy just these 14 rows not all of them (not all the 335 of them) but now the code is copying all of them.
Anyone can help to modify the code?
Here is the code:
function copyDataFromParksToReport() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var parksSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Parks');
  var reportSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Report');
  
  reportSheet.getRange('A2:M').clearContent();
  
  var parksData = parksSheet.getRange('A4:Q').getValues();
  
  var reportData = [];
  
  parksData.forEach(function(row) {
    var newRow = [];
    newRow[0] = row[16]; // Column Q -> Column A
    newRow[1] = row[0]; // Column A -> Column B
    newRow[2] = row[4]; // Column E -> Column C
    newRow[3] = row[3]; // Column D -> Column D
    newRow[4] = row[1]; // Column B -> Column E
    newRow[5] = row[5]; // Column F -> Column F
    newRow[6] = row[8]; // Column I -> Column G
    newRow[8] = row[10]; // Column K -> Column I
    newRow[10] = row[9]; // Column J -> Column K
    newRow[12] = row[12]; // Column M -> Column M
    
    // Get File ID from Google Drive links
    if (row[6].includes("drive.google.com")) {
      newRow[7] = row[6].split("/")[5]; // Column G -> Column H
    } else {
      newRow[7] = '';
    }
    if (row[11].includes("drive.google.com")) {
      newRow[11] = row[11].split("/")[5]; // Column L -> Column L
    } else {
      newRow[11] = '';
    }
    
    reportData.push(newRow);
  });
  
  reportSheet.getRange(2, 1, reportData.length, reportData[0].length).setValues(reportData);
}


I have tried the getfilter class but it didn't work.
After applying filter:

Before applying filter:

After running code + after applying filter:


Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this anonymous sheet maker to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.

i wanna apply filter on sheet 'Parks' How/where is the filter selected; what column of the data does the filter refer to? Is this question about how to select the filter, how to apply the filter, how to trigger the script or all the above?

for many different requests, i need to apply different kind of filters so i can't mention any. i edited my question and added 3 images to show what i mean. Jats PPG almost got what i need

Use isRowHiddenByFilter() to Fetch
Since getVisibleValues() is not working to fetch the filtered data, I have used an alternate solution, which is the isRowHiddenByFilter() to get the not hidden by the filter.
I have changed the whole code to get your desired output.
Modified Script
 function getVisibleValuesInColumn() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Parks");
  var vl = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var op = vl.filter((_, i) => !sh.isRowHiddenByFilter(i + 1));
  console.log(op);
  var rp = ss.getSheetByName("Report");
  rp.clear();
  ss.getSheetByName("Report").getRange(1, 1, op.length, op[0].length).setValues(op);
}

Sample Output

References:

isRowHiddenByFilter(rowPosition)

Logical NOT (!)



If there is something not in the result, feel free to comment so that I can adjust my answer based on your expected result.

Dear Jats PPG Thank you so much for understanding my question. i ran your modified code but problem still remained. after applying a filter on sheet parks, 4 rows displayed but the result on sheet Report is with 335 rows

Can you share the filter that you are trying to run?

Also, would you be able to share a sample sheet with your initial output and expected output? You may use this Anonymous Sheet Maker to create your sample sheet without your email being exposed.

here is my file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qSS94xlt8Ma-qs0hOwLbjDOXszpUj73v9p6RMXhbquU/edit?usp=sharing

Please share a public spreadsheet containing your sample data so that the community may replicate your issue easily. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

LINK IS PUBLIC NOW

The link that you have sent here still needs access. You need to make sure that the community can access it without needing to sign in. Also, please edit your question and include your spreadsheet link.

@Kimiagar  I have updated my answer to fit your desired result. Let me know if you have any questions regarding my answer so that I can edit it.
